# Qual a diferença entre feature detection e feature inference

Tags: javascript

Queria saber qual a principal diferença entre as duas formas ***feature detection*** e ***feature inference***.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Feature detection** consiste em verificar se a função está disponível para ser utilizada, explicitamente.

**Feature inference** consiste em verificar se uma função está disponível e, baseado nisso, supor que uma outra também estará.

**Feature Detection:**

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

**Feature inference:**

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName){
element = document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Fonte: [Pergunta SO En](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104930/whats-the-difference-between-feature-detection-feature-inference-and-using-th)