# Como descobrir a versão do JavaScript (via código)?

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma maneira simples [ou não] de descobrir qual é a versão do JavaScript que está sendo utilizada em um determinado navegador - pelo próprio código escrito em JavaScript?

Algo como:

```
console.log(javascript.version);
```

Isso poderia ser útil caso faltasse algum recurso em uma versão anterior.

Exemplo:

```
if (javascript.version < 1.5) {
   throw new Error("Método 'bind' não existe nessa versão');
}
```

Comment: Só por curiosidade, qual o propósito?

Comment: Saber a versão do javascript :D

Comment: Na verdade, poderia ser útil caso faltasse algum recurso em uma versão anterior

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340726/detect-version-of-javascript (útlima resposta)

Comment: Alguém poderia explicar o motivo do _Downvote_? Quando dou _Downvote_, faço com propósito!

Comment: Tem pessoas que fazem por puro luxo. Algumas perguntas são boas, vai gente que dá downvote e não dá um parecer pelo motivo pelo qual votou dessa forma, deixando a pessoa com a dúvida e sem nenhuma resposta.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Não** existe um maneira confiável de descobrir a versão do JavaScript.

O uso de `<script language="Javascript1.*">` não tem *precisão*, um exemplo de problema é que em alguns navegadores você pode usar um atributo `language="Javascript1.7"` mas ainda sim poderá usar funções somente suportadas no `language="Javascript1.9"`.

Outro problema é no *InternetExplorer9* por exemplo, ele suporta várias funcionalidades que deveriam já ser no mínimo *Javascript1.5*, mas ele apresenta sempre *Javascript1.3*.

O mesmo ocorre com o Firefox que sempre apresenta o resultado de Javascript1.5.

Como já dito em outras respostas não há função para detectar a versão do motor JavaScript, note que cada navegador tem um *motor JavaScript* próprio e muitas vezes tal versão não representa as funcionalidades que realmente ele possui.

Se você se basear por tais dados é capaz de desabilitar funções úteis e suportadas que pela lógica não deveriam ser suportadas em tal versão do JavaScript.

Isto ocorre porque na verdade desde o inicio da batalha dos navegadores, quando a microsoft lançou o seu próprio motor javascript (chamado `jscript`) e o Netscape lançou o dele, com muitas características diferentes (por incrível que pareça o InternetExplorer naquela época era bem melhor nisto que os concorrentes).

Não existia um padrão e só com o surgimento do [*ECMAScript*](http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC39.htm) passamos a ter um padrão (o desenvolvimento desta especificação começou em Novembro de 1996 e foi adotado pela *Ecma General Assembly* em junho de 1997, conforme o documento pdf no link citado).

Acredito que hoje estamos no ECMAScript 7, mas não quer dizer que os navegadores suportem todas características.

Veja assim, imagine que temos duas tecnologias do ECMAScript 6 (é só um exemplo imaginário):

- `window.minhaFuncaoHelloWordEcma6`
- `window.minhaFuncaoFooEcma6`

O Chorme lançou a função `window.minhaFuncaoHelloWordEcma6`, mas não suporta `window.minhaFuncaoFooEcma6`, então o navegador não pode ser EcmaScript6 e nem EcmaScript5 pois no 5 não existe `window.minhaFuncaoHelloWordEcma6` e para ser o 6 é necessário `window.minhaFuncaoFooEcma6`.

Então identificar a versão do JavaScript ou EcmaScript nunca será possível, a não ser que todos navegadores sigam rigorosamente o padrão e só deem suportes para novos métodos quando todos deixarem de ser experimentais (ou que é inviável e tornaria o processo de atualização muito mais lento).

Note que hoje usamos muitas funcionalidades experimentais, então não use:

```
<script language="Javascript1.9">
    jsver = 1.9;
</script>
```

Pois você nunca terá o resultado esperado em navegadores diferentes.

### JavaScript e Mozilla

Conforme este comentário no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469240/invalid-left-hand-side-in-assignment-javascript1-7#comment16773593_12469267):

> Google-chrome support EcmaScript 3.1 and parts of EcmaScript 5. JavaScript 1.7 is a Mozilla creation. No other browsers support JavaScript > 1.5, and instead support varying versions of EcmaScript. See [Relationship between JavaScript and EcmaScript version numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction#Relationship_between_JavaScript_Versions_and_ECMAScript_Editions) - *Mike Samuel*

E o comentário do @bfavareto:

> Não quer acrescentar que essas versões "1.x" valem apenas para browsers da Mozilla? Que é quem tem o copyright da marca *JavaScript*, por sinal. – bfavaretto

JavaScript foi originalmente desenvolvido por *Brendan Eich* da *Netscape* sob o nome de *Mocha*, posteriormente teve seu nome mudado para LiveScript e por fim JavaScript.

Como consequência, a Microsoft desenvolveu um dialeto compatível com a linguagem de nome JScript para evitar problemas de marca registrada, em outras palavras o termos Javascript é foi registrado pela antiga Netscape (hoje Mozilla - estou falando da empresa).

Então JavaScript1.7 é uma criação da Mozilla e por isto a maioria dos navegadores **"não Mozilla"**, só irão funcionar até javascript1.3 ou javascript1.5, pois eles se padronizaram para seguir as versões de implantações conforme o ES, então o que atualiza hoje é o motor do JavaScript (junto ao navegador).

<sub>Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Hist.C3.B3ria</sub>

### Conclusão

- Não é possível detectar a versão do JavaScript
- Mesmo que o navegador fale que está usando Javascript1.3 ele pode já estar em uma suposta versão bem superior
- Um navegador pode supostamente usar uma versão do JavaScript e apresentar algumas **"features"** que não deveriam existir em tal versão.
- Não é possível detectar a versão de compatibilidade completa com as versões do ECMAScript (a não ser que você crie uma biblioteca com todos tipos de testes possíveis, o que parece inviável)

Siga o que foi dito pelo @Maniero, use o [**Feature Detection**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19011/3635)

### Recomendação

Recomendo que ao invés de detectar a versão do JavaScript ou EcmaScript tente detectar se a função é suportada, por exemplo:

```
function minhaFuncao(arg1) {
    if (typeof window.minhaFuncaoFooEcma6 === "function") {
       return window.minhaFuncaoFooEcma6(arg1);
   }

   return false;
}
```

> <s>**Nota:** Em uma outra resposta minha eu adicione alguns exemplos de como detectar as funcionalidades de maneira mais "segura": [Como Detectar Recursos DOM e API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/138441/3635)</s>

Comment: Você concorda com a minha, porque coloquei o que ele quis mas eu disse que isto não serve pra nada útil. Coloquei uma alternativa e *links* mostrando o que deve ser feito. Portanto eu concordo com a sua, exceto pela parte que você discorda das outras :P Talvez da mais votada que só deu o que ele queria mas não fala nada que isto não é algo que útil.

Comment: @bigown eu tinha linkado apenas a do onosendai e a do SOen, não linkei a sua resposta, talvez tenha dado a entender errado. Vou remover tal trecho da resposta.

Comment: A discordância em si acho pertinente, é que do jeito que estava escrito dava a entender que discordava de todas e a minha ia no mesmo sentido da sua.

Comment: Não é recomendado usar nada especificado no ECMAScript 6 ainda, poucas features são suportadas e nem sempre são as mesmas entre os navegadores: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: [editado] @DontVoteMeDown exatamente é isto que o meu exemplo sugere, não é possivel determinar nem a versão do Javascript e nem a versão do ES. Pois se o navegador usa-se ES5 com alguma função do ES6 ele já não seria ES5 e nem ES6. E por isto sugeri a *"Recomendação"*: *Recomendo que ao invés de detectar a versão do javascript ou ecmascript tente detectar se a função é suportada*

Comment: Sim, sua resposta faz todo o sentido. Por isso dei um up. Comentei mais por causa da fonte que coloquei, pra quem não conhece pode ser útil.

Comment: Não quer acrescentar que essas versões "1.x" valem apenas para browsers da Mozilla? Que é quem tem o copyright da marca *JavaScript*, por sinal.

Comment: @bfavaretto Verdade, obrigado eu editei a resposta :)

Answer (score 6):

Pelo código, de uma maneira geral não tem como. Não existe uma função ou uma variável que indique isto. Existem técnicas para você descobrir se realmente for necessário. Mas você terá que cuidar disto e vejo pouca ou nenhuma vantagem. O [melhor que achei foi isto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271622/221800):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsver = 1.0;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.1">
  jsver = 1.1;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.2">
  jsver = 1.2;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.3">
  jsver = 1.3;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.4">
  jsver = 1.4;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.5">
  jsver = 1.5;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.6">
  jsver = 1.6;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.7">
  jsver = 1.7;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.8">
  jsver = 1.8;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.9">
  jsver = 1.9;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(jsver);
</script>
```

[Importante leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19010/101). [Outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30238/101)

---

Eu acho melhor detectar a versão do navegador do que do JS. Faz pouco sentido detectar a versão do JS. Então vou manter aqui minha resposta original.

Achei esta [função no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5918791/221800):

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/);
        if(tem!= null) return 'Opera '+tem[1];
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return M.join(' ');
})();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Browser/Detection.js).

Não sei dizer se ela é a melhor possível ou se continua 100% válida. Eu não gosto de confiar em coisas deste tipo. Mas se não tem nada melhor...

Na mesma pergunta tem outras versões. Deve existir um motivo para não usar:

```
BrowserDetect.version
```

É uma das respostas, mas ela é pouco votada. Espero que especialistas possam dizer porque não usá-lo.

Comment: Retornou "Firefox 39". Isso seria a versão do JS ou do Navegador?

Comment: Essa é a versão do Browser, creio que ele queira a do JS.

Comment: Tá certo, eu entendi o que você quer. vou mudar.

Comment: Já está corrigida. É, eu acho que `BrowserDetect´ é específico. O mais importante da resposta não é a solução, mas sim você saber que isto não te ajuda na prática que não é esta informação que você deve buscar para nada normal.

Comment: Pronto. Agora a justiça foi feita. A pergunta não foi feita só pra descobrir a versão, já que, se eu quero saber a versão, é por algum motivo. E a questão de saber versão do browser para determinar o uso de recursos parece ser sempre utilizada na maioria do casos

Comment: Eu não usaria "detectar a versão", porque isto não garante se a tecnologia está presente por dois fatores, o primeiro é que existem características que podem ser desabilitadas pelo usuário e segundo porque existe maneira de modificar o User-Agent fazendo você se passar por outro navegador @WallaceMaxters

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento isso mesmo, por isso passei os dois *links* na parte principal da resposta mostrando que a *feature detection* é o que deve ser usado.

Comment: @bigown entendo o que você disse, mas como eu marquei o Wallace com o `@` foi por causa deste comentário dele: *E a questão de saber versão do browser para determinar o uso de recursos parece ser sempre utilizada na maioria do casos*, mesmo com os links passados me parece que o entendimento dele foi outro.

Comment: O "entendimento" que cheguei foi devido às muitas alterações e um pouco de pressa, confesso (pois estou na maioiria das vezes trabalhando quando surge essas questões). A minha leitura foi dinâmica, mas entendi o que vocês quiseram passar. Obrigado por demonstrar o `Feature Detection`.

Comment: Espero que não me julguem por ter marcado a outra resposta como resolvida, mas creio que nesse caso é mais conveniente que seja assim :)

Comment: Hoje estou premiado, é um negativo atrás do outro.

Answer (score 4):

Via compilação condicional:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsver = 1.0;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.1">
  jsver = 1.1;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.2">
  jsver = 1.2;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.3">
  jsver = 1.3;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.4">
  jsver = 1.4;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.5">
  jsver = 1.5;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.6">
  jsver = 1.6;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.7">
  jsver = 1.7;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.8">
  jsver = 1.8;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.9">
  jsver = 1.9;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(jsver);
</script>
```

Meu Chrome atual reporta a versão 1.7.

Fontes: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271566/how-do-i-know-which-version-of-javascript-im-using), [#2](http://javascript.about.com/library/bljver.htm).

Comment: O.o. No meu mostrou `1.5`. Estou usando Firefox  39

Comment: A resposta aceita na minha recomendação utiliza essa mesma estratégia, portanto, eu iria por esse caminho que o @OnoSendai postou.

Comment: @cantoni correto - eu não tinha visto seu comentário. Poste como resposta, para que possamos votar.

Comment: Sem problemas @OnoSendai. Deixa assim. Tá tudo certo. :-)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Testei aqui, e posso confirmar - 1.5 no FF.

Comment: no meu FF (39.0.3) também retornou 1.5.

Comment: Se estiver usando o PHP, dá pra fazer um `for` para não ter que repitir código. Ou então usar o próprio javascript para incluir via `document.createelement('script')`

Comment: IE - 1.3. Meio que explica certos comportamentos... [Edit] Edge (Windows 10) também reporta 1.3.

Comment: Safari ultima versão (8.0.7) retorna 1.7