# Por que esse setTimeout não funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Meu objetivo é quando eu clicar no botão, 3 segundos depois uma `div` releia a página...

Por que esse código não funciona?

```
<button id="btn-cadastra-tarefa" ng-click="adicionaTarefa()" onclick="atualiza()" 
        type="button" data-dismiss="modal" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>Salvar
</button>

<div id="atualizaPagina"></div>

function atualiza() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#atualizaPagina').location.reload(); }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Não posso afirmar, mas o método `location` não estende para elementos HTML.

Comment: "depois uma div seja dada F5", que dados você quer atribuir a essa div?

Comment: Você quer atualizar a página toda ou apenas a div criada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se realmente a necessidade for atualizar a página **toda** você pode usar:

Funciona no IE:

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = window.location.href; }, 3000);
```

Não testei em todos navegadores, pode não funcionar em algum:

```
setTimeout(function(){ location = '' }, 3000);
setTimeout(function () { location.reload(); }, 3000);
```

---

Para recarregar uma página via javascript você pode usar uma das seguintes opções:

#### Javascript 1.0

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname + "pagina";
```

> Cria entrada no histórico de páginas

#### Javascript 1.1

```
window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + "pagina");
```

> Não cria entrada no histórico de páginas

#### Javascript 1.2

```
window.location.reload();
```

> Recarrega página do cache

```
window.location.reload(false);
```

> Recarrega página do cache

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

> Recarrega página do servidor (força novo GET)

Comment: Javascript 1.0, 1.1, 1.2? Desculpe mas isto não parece fazer sentido, JavaScript foi uma tecnologia proposta pela netscape (antiga Mozilla), essas versões só fazem lógica nele, fora que hoje em dia todos navegadores suportam essas funções, menos o true no reload. Leia isto: [Como descobrir a versão do JavaScript (via código)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80001/3635)

Answer (score 5):

Majoritariamente, porque ele não faz sentido.

`$('#atualizaPagina')` retorna um elemento HTML e nenhum elemento HTML tem a propriedade `location`, consequentemente, não existe o método `reload()`.

Se quiser atualizar a página toda use `window.location.reload()`. Não existe nenhum método de atualizar uma div, até porque não faria sentido. Atualizaria com base no quê?

O que você deve estar querendo fazer realmente é apenas modificar os dados que são mostrados nesta div, pra isso, você precisa fazer uma chamada Ajax pro *backend* e depois **atualizar a div** via JavaScript com base na resposta da sua chamada Ajax.

Eu não tenho como mostrar um exemplo com código porque esta parte do código não existe na pergunta.

Veja um exemplo genérico que faz uma requisição Ajax e depois atualiza a tag `img`:

```js
const reqUrl = 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=9e4393bfcf774cd08e0757b4688b11f7&q=javascript';

$('#ajax').on('click', function() {
  $.get(reqUrl, function(r) {
    $('#img').attr('src', r.data[0].images.original.url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ajax">Faça uma requisição Ajax</button><br>

<img id="img" src="http://netcoders.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/js3.png" width="250" height="250" />
```

Comment: isso não atualizaria a página toda? Se entendi bem, a ideia é atualizar apenas a div. Acho que precisaria de algum código `ajax` pra isso

Comment: @rLinhares Ela fala em "dar F5". Normalmente isso é atualizar a página toda, mas pelo código, faz sentido o que tu disse.

Comment: Sim, a intenção é dar F5 e atualizar os dados