# Futuro do Javascript, como saber das possíveis features/novidades da linguagem?

Tags: javascript

É um fato que o Javascript tem crescido muito nos últimos anos e tem se tornado cada vez maior, mas qual seria os caminhos para se manter antenado em relação as novas features?

Temos o [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Quais são os locais oficiais de propostas de features novas?

Como saber o cronograma de aceite/exclusão de uma feature nova?

Apesar de não ser uma pergunta técnica, ela faz sentido pois a comunidade precisa de um mapa.

Comment: Talvez isto https://www.ecma-international.org/news/index.html e isto https://ecmascript-daily.github.io/ ... estou votando pra fechar, pq mesmo q a pergunta seja interessante, não é bem o lugar para se perguntar, lembrando que o você pode usar o chat oficial do site https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha...

Comment: ... Ainda sim preciso dizer, com ou sem novidades, muita coisa do ES6 em diante, em sintaxe, me parece firulas, e poderia escrever facilmente o mesmo em ES5, muita coisa é pura moda. Agora sobre as APIs, é preciso entender que mesmo existindo na especificação (ECMAScript) não significa que os navegadores irão suportar de pronta, é bem provavel que muitas implementações levem tempo, e tem que observar se é "Draft" (rascunho), pq nem tudo q esta em ideia ainda significa que será aprovado no ECMA.

Comment: Eu geralmente não negativo, só quando a pergunta é um erro de digitação ou é SPAM, agora votar pra fechar eu votei, e eu inclusive respondi nos comentários, não vejo resposta além do que eu já comentei, não entendo o que você espera, a pergunta não é um duvida com algoritimos, linguagem e nem softwares, então não é escopo, mas vou formular uma resposta antes que venha alguém e responda qualquer ou copie os comentários e responda, pq infelizmente (apesar de poucos) isso as vezes ocorre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro é preciso entender que não é porque uma função, método, API ou sintaxe novas são definidas que isso vai existir *magicamente* em todos navegadores, definir algo só diz como algo deve ser, quem defini nem cria a implementação interna, ou seja não codificam nada, no entanto não pense mal deles, é graça a eles (que logo vou citar quem são) que diferenças entre navegadores foram sendo diminuídas.

### JavaScript e EcmaScript

Quase tudo que precisamos falar disto eu expliquei https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80001/3635, leia antes por favor, então vou dar uma breve resumida:

- A Netscape (empresa), na época com o navegador de mesmo nome criou um dialeto para tornar o navegador mais dinâmico que teve 3 nomes, o ultimo JavaScript (nada relacionado com Java)
- A Microsoft para não deixar seu navegador pra trás criou um equivalente chamado JScript

Resumindo cada empresa tinha seu dialeto/linguagem, parecidos, mas não iguais, então depois veio a ECMAScript um dialeto em 1997, ou seja as linguagens de ambos navegadores e outros navegadores aderiram ao ECMAScript, mas claro ainda sim cada um (e novos) implementaram suas próprias funcionalidades, APIs, etc.

Ok, então apesar de chamarmos tudo de JavaScript, não é necessariamente isto, só é popular chamar, talvez como chamar esponja de aço por uma marca achando que aquele é nome de todas.

### Como saber o que é novidade

Tendo entendido quem e o quê define os "JavaScripts" de cada navegador (ou "motor", por diferentes navegadores podem usar o mesmo motor, o caso do novo Edge, usará Chromium) agora podemos ir para o ponto principal, não é porque a ECMA lançou algo novo no ECMAScript, do qual você pode acompanhar em:

- https://www.ecma-international.org/news/index.html

Que significará que um navegador irá de pronto imediato, a ECMA só define, quem desenvolve os motores dos navegadores terá que transformar as normas em código funcionais e ainda talvez tenha que adaptar isto para diferentes sistemas operacionais como:

- Mobiles
- MacOS
- Diferentes Linux
- Windows

Ou seja, lançou no ECMA não significa que você poderá sair usando, então para saber quando um navegador disponibilizará a nova funcionalidade é só acompanhando os changelogs

### Changelogs dos principais navegadores

- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/changelog/
- https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/

PS: Eu diria que não só JavaScript, mas qualquer linguagem de programação, quer ver novidades? Então acompanhe o changelog nos site oficiais, isso seria mais que suficiente para uma resposta, só o JavaScript tive que estender porque ele é um pouco mais complicado de se entender.

### DevTools de navegadores baseados em Chromium

No entanto para sua felicidade, se usa Chrome e você é desenvolvedor então com certeza você usa o DevTools, apertando F12 geralmente, irá notar embaixo um "What's news", nele contêm mudanças interessante, nem todas haver com JavaScript, muitas haver com o DevTools e até com CSS, mas as vezes aparece algo com JavaScript, mas depende do que foi lançado, exemplo:

> [image: devtools mostrando novidades]

No Opera, Edge (novo), Vivaldi, Bravo, etc, que são baseados em Chromium, todos irão apresentar o mesmo, mas claro que nem todos vão acompanhar o Chrome ou Chromium em tempo, no entanto posteriormente vão passar exatamente pelo mesmo