# Listar fontes do sistema ou diretorio para um dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ha possibilidade em javascript ou outra linguagem de listar as fontes instaladas no sistema ou dentro de um diretorio  e colocar no drop down?

```js
   function changeFont(font){
        document.getElementById("preview").style.fontFamily = font.value;
    }
```

```html
<select id="input-font" class="input"  onchange="changeFont (this);">
            <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
            <option value="Sans Serif" selected>Sans Serif</option>
            <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
            <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
            <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
            <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
            <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
            <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
            <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
            <option value="Bookman">Bookman</option>
            <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
            <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div id="preview" style="margin:auto;width:50%;height:40px;font-size:32px;text-align:center;background-color:black;color:#fff;">Seu 
        Texto</div>
```

Comment: Você não tem controle dessas fonts no seu css ou dir?

Comment: nao, o intuito e so pegar as fontes mesmo do sistema

Comment: esse sistema é feito em com qual framework?

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62755574/8839059) do SOen. Tem outras respostas na mesma pergunta, mas das que li, essa parecia o melhor caminho. @edit: entendi a pergunta errada, a resposta que mencionei não verifica um diretório, mas sim as fontes do sistema.

Answer (score 2):

Existe o [**`navigator.fonts`**](https://web.dev/local-fonts/), que só é suportado pelos navegadores baseados em *Chromium* e também precisa ser habilitado pelo endereço **`chrome://flags/#font-access`** (desde o Chrome 87)

E também existe o [**`document.fonts.check()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts) e funciona nos seguintes navegadores:

| Chrome | Edge | Firefox | Opera | Safari | WebView Android | Chrome Android | Firefox Android | Opera Android | Safari iOS | Samsung Internet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | 79 | 41 | 22 | 10 | 4.4.3 | 35 | 41 | 22 | 10 | 3.0+ |

---

### Usando o `navigator.fonts`

Em resumo ao usar isso o usuário vai dizer quais ele permite o seu site acessar, lembre-se que isso não pode ser iniciado automaticamente, só por ação do usuário, por exemplo detectando via `onclick`, se tentar com `onload` vai causar o erro:

> DOMException: User activation is required.

Um exemplo bem simples:

```
<button id="carregar-fonts">Carregar fontes</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('carregar-fonts').onclick = fontes;

async function fontes() {
    if ('fonts' in navigator) {
        try {
            const fonts = await navigator.fonts.query();

            for (let i = 0, j = fonts.length; i < j; i++) {
                console.log(fonts[i].fullName);
            }
        } catch (ee) {
            console.error(ee);
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Seu navegador não tem suporte a navigator.fonts');
    }
}
</script>
```

Após executar será mostrado isso ao usuário para ele confirmar quais ele permite (afinal as fontes "são" do usuário):

[image: permitir fontes]

> **Nota 1:** Ao invés de `await` também pode usar `Promise.then()`/`Promise.catch()`, mas vai depender de suas necessidades.
>
> **Nota 2:** foi usado `if ('fonts' in navigator) {` para fazer uma [checagem do recurso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80001/3635) no navegador atual.

---

### Usando o `document.fonts.check()`

O uso do [`document.fonts.check()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts) irá checar um fonte por vez, assim:

```
document.fonts.check("10px Arial");
```

Então nesse caso não vai obter todas fontes, você terá que enumerar as fontes que deseja testar (adicionar ao seu select talvez), exemplo:

Exemplo para testar com array:

```js
if ('fonts' in document) {
    const fonts = [
        'Arial',
        'Sans Serif',
        'Comic Sans MS',
        'Times New Roman',
        'Courier New',
        'Verdana',
        'Trebuchet MS',
        'Arial Black',
        'Impact',
        'Bookman',
        'Garamond',
        'Palatino',
        'Georgia',
    ];

    document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
      for (let i = 0, j = fonts.length; i < j; i++) {
        const font = fonts[i];
        const valid = document.fonts.check(`12px ${font}`);

        console.log(font, valid);
      }
    });
} else {
    console.error('Seu navegador não suporta navigator.fonts');
}
```

No Firefox infelizmente existe um bug, que toda fonte (mesmo que não exista) retorna `true` nesse método, aparentemente isso foi reportado no **bugzilla**:

- [[CSS Font Loading] document.fonts.check / FontFaceSet.check returns 'true' for unkown fonts](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1252821)