# Simular browser sem suporte para HTML5

Tags: html, html5, navegador-de-internet

Estou desenvolvendo um site que pode ser aberto em um navegador sem suporte para HTML5 (canvas, etc).

Gostaria de realizar testes, para isso basta mudar o User Agent ou existe uma ferramenta específica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou usando o IE11 e apesar dos pesares possui a melhor ferramenta que pude encontrar até o momento.

Em suas **Ferramentas para Desenvolvedores (F12)** existe disponível a aba **[Emulação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx)** , e na opção **Modo de documento** estão disponíveis algumas versões justamente para testes de compatibilidade.

Exemplo: O Canvas só é suportado a partir do IE9*, então ao selecionar a opção 8 em Modo de documento, não consigo usar canvas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*[Referencia1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_(HTML5)#Suporte), [Referencia2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas)

Answer (score 2):

A melhor forma é instalar uma versão antiga de um navegador. Mudar o *user-agent* não resolve na maioria dos casos. Pelo menos se você faz [*feature detection*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19010/101) que é o correto.

Outra possibilidade é [usar uma extensão no FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html5toggle-toggle-html5-su/) ou [no Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf?hl=en), mas não sei se elas se comportam bem.

Também pode tentar uma [ferramenta que mostre o resultado em diversos navegadores](http://browsershots.org/) para você. Raramente será uma solução mas é uma alternativa.

Técnicas de desenvolvimento onde se faz o básico sem envolver recursos disponíveis em navegadores modernos e depois ir adicionando outros recursos ao site pode ajudar no desenvolvimento.

Comment: Bem, a extensão do Firefox não funciona na versão atual e a do Chrome não achei muito intuitiva. O link da ferramenta com resultado em diversos navegadores é interessante, mas infelizmente eu necessitaria de algo em tempo de desenvolvimento. Postei uma resposta com uma possível solução que encontrei nas tentativas continuadas.